# How to get just opened pages not chrome special pages in my own extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to get opened tabs but not opened empty new tabs, bookmarks tab, download tabs and etc. How can I do it?

Comment: `chrome://` vs `https://`

Comment: If I want to create my extension for all browsers then I must be change this? There is no any simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*://*/*` where the first `*` matches `http` and `https`, [more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) in the documentation.

```js
chrome.tabs.query({url: '*://*/*'}, tabs => {
  // process tabs here
});
```

If you want to include `file://` tabs too:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({url: ['*://*/*', 'file://*/*']}, tabs => {
  // process tabs here
});
```